# Convert UTC timestamp from database into Users Local time

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, smarty

Question: How do I Display a UTC timestamp from a database table in a users local time? Is there any way to do this with php?

**Extra Context \/**
I have an application that saves the date records are added to the database.I am saving the records in the database using mysql `UTC_TIMESTAMP()`. I then want to display the record to the user in their local time in my Smarty template.

```
{$dateAdded|smarty_modifier:"%D %R %Z"}
```

I have tried smarty, date_format as the modifier but I just get the UTC time and the persons timezone, which of course is correct but not the result that I want.

```
02/11/11 20:32 Pacific Standard Time
```

I need the time so be set to the user's local time

```
02/11/11 12:32 Pacific Standard Time
```

Is it correct to store the date of the transaction in UTC, and how do I display that UTC to the user in their local time? Is there a way to pull the date out of the database so that it is set to the users current local time?

Comment: I'd at least do the date conversion in PHP rather than smarty, if not the formatting as well.

Comment: Smarty is written in php so by using smarty I am doing the conversion and the formattion in php.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`date_default_timezone_set()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) prior invoking the Smarty template. That defines directly how the UTC timestamps are adapted to the expected output timezone.

Comment: Not sure how this helps me mate. From the documentation: "Sets the default timezone used by all date/time functions in a script"http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: I have downvoted until you are able to provide an adequate explanation.